# elasticsearch must multivalue search

Tags: elasticsearch

My elasticsearch version is 2.4,

I have issue when I use multivalue search with must clause.
In the below elasticsearch query I search the query "polo tshirt" and country "us"

but It's gives the no relevant data of query "polo tshirt".

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query" : {                     
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match" :{
                    "common" : {
                        "_all" : {
                            "query" : "polo tshirt",                                            
                            "minimum_should_match" : '100%'
                        }
                    }
                },
                "match" : { "country" : "us"}
            }                           
        }
    },
    "sort" : [
    {"review" :{"order" :"desc"}}
    ]     
}'
```

Comment: For a multiple `must` You would use `must: [ { }, { }]`. Also avoid using `_all`. You can index specific terms which you want to search on and then use that terms here as they would return more specific results. Like product name and description

Comment: Hi @MohamedSanaulla thanks the answe, but I didn't use the specific term because I have lots of other properties so I need to use "_all".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must should be used with [].

```
 {
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "common": {
                "_all": {
                    "query": "polo tshirt",
                    "minimum_should_match": "100%"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "match": {
                "country": "us"
            }

        }]
    }
},
"sort": [{
    "review": {
        "order": "desc"
    }
}]
}
```